# Knowing a twitter application name, how to find out who owns it?

Tags: twitter

I would like to find the owning account of a twitter application. Anyone knows if there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you browse to [enter link description here](https://twitter.com/settings/applications), you can see the apps that are authorized to your account.  The individual app authors may or may not link to a web page.  That's as much information as you can get.

Comment: Thanks, DWRoelands. The app is not authorized to my account.